# Filter Dataframe based on index and value of a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter specific rows of a dataframe using a Series. As an example,

```
import pandas as pd
filter_ = pd.Series(
    data = [1, 9, 10],
    index = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    )
filter_.index.name = 'my_id'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 9, 4],
    'B': [9, 6, 7, 8],
    'C': [10, 91, 32, 13],
    'D': [43, 12, 7, 9],
    'E': [65, 12, 3, 8]
})
```

I now want to filter the dataframe so that I get the row where the indices and values of the Series match the columns and values of the dataframe, i.e., the result should be

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   9   10  43  65
```

From what I can tell, `.query()` doesn't work as one of my values in my actaul dataframe is a pathlib object.

Something like `df.loc[df[filter.index[0]] == filter.iloc[0]]` works, but obviously only filters over the index `A`, while I want to be able to dynamically filter over all the index/value pairs in the Series.

---

Edited: Some of the solutions given weren't working with my actual dataframe as there were `None` values included in some columns. I previously included a fuller output, that showed us what the difference was between the full example and the MWE.

---

## Timings

TL,DR: the method given by Panda is fastest for large dataframes, while the answer by TheHungryCub is fastest for very small dataframes but increases significantly depending on the complexity.

I've now tested the example given by Panda Kim below including the `None` values:

```
import pandas as pd
filter_ = pd.Series(
data = [1, 9, None],
index = ['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object'
)
filter_.index.name = 'my_id'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 9, 4],
    'B': [9, 6, 7, 8],
    'C': [None, None, None, None],
    'D': [43, 12, 7, 9],
    'E': [65, 12, 3, 8]
})
```

Using `%%timeit`, the timings were as follows:

```
col1 = filter_.index[filter_.notna()]
col2 = filter_.index.difference(col1)
cond = df[col1].eq(filter_[col1]).all(axis=1) & df[col2].isna().all(axis=1)
out = df[cond]
```

911 µs ± 26.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

--

```
out = df[df[filter_.index].fillna(object).eq(filter_.fillna(object)).all(axis=1)]
```

421 µs ± 6.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

--

```
out = df[df.apply(lambda row: all(row[index] == value for index, value in filter_.items()), axis=1)]
```

200 µs ± 5.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

--

Thus, it seems as if using `.apply()` actaully works fastest. Adding  `+ list(range(1000))` to every column in the dataframe (so that it has 10004 rows in total) shows quite different results, with the first method taking 1.31 ms, the second taking 1.53 ms, and the third (`.apply()`) taking 43.5 ms. Scaling up to 1 million rows shows that the first method takes 38.2 ms, the second 125 ms, and the third takes 4.55 seconds.

Comment: I renamed `filter` to `filter_` since `filter` is a python builtin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the null values. It seems like we need to handle them separately for vectorize operation.

Let's regenerate the example to include null values.

**New example**

```
import pandas as pd
filter_ = pd.Series(
    data = [1, 9, None],
    index = ['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object'
)
filter_.index.name = 'my_id'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 9, 4],
    'B': [9, 6, 7, 8],
    'C': [None, None, None, None],
    'D': [43, 12, 7, 9],
    'E': [65, 12, 3, 8]
})
```

**Code**

```
col1 = filter_.index[filter_.notna()]
col2 = filter_.index.difference(col1)
cond = df[col1].eq(filter_[col1]).all(axis=1) & df[col2].isna().all(axis=1)
out = df[cond]
```

out

```
    A   B   C       D   E
0   1   9   None    43  65
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice `df` with the indices of `filter_`, compare the two, then aggregate with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df[filter_.index].eq(filter_).all(axis=1)]
```

If you can have NaNs, then use a dummy object (e.g. `object`) to replace them before comparison:

```
out = df[df[filter_.index].fillna(object).eq(filter_.fillna(object)).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   A  B   C   D   E
0  1  9  10  43  65
```

Comment: This works for the question as asked, unfortuantely it doesn't work for my complexer dataframe. Perhaps because I am actaully filtering my `_filter` first, i.e. I have more columns than `index_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']` and then do `filter_rows = _filter[index_columns]`

Comment: I see, let me update. Let me know if this works, else please provide the output of `df.columns` and `filter_.index` from the real dataset

Comment: I've updated my post with the outputs of the original df. The safer version also doens't work, although checking for overlapping column names shouldn't make a difference as I've previously already ensured that the column names are identical

Comment: @mozway If it was a column issue, an error would have been raised, and the same goes for the previous answer. It seems like there is a different problem since your answer did not raise an error but returned an empty DataFrame.

Comment: @Luke I see, you have NaNs, so those compare unequal in pandas. See update

Comment: Hey, yeah seems those were the problem. A maybe trivial question, but why does oandas still output the NaN's if I fill them with object? Is it simply that it's not happening inplace and so the original df is not modified?

Comment: @Luke since the fillna is only used for filtering, they won't end up in the output. This could be done though if desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.all()` to check if all elements in the boolean Series are True for each row.

```
import pandas as pd

filter_ = pd.Series(
    data=[1, 9, 10],
    index=['A', 'B', 'C']
)
filter_.index.name = 'my_id'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 9, 4],
    'B': [9, 6, 7, 8],
    'C': [10, 91, 32, 13],
    'D': [43, 12, 7, 9],
    'E': [65, 12, 3, 8]
})

filtered_rows = df[df.apply(lambda row: all(row[index] == value for index, value in filter_.items()), axis=1)]

print(filtered_rows)
```

Output:

```
   A  B   C   D   E
0  1  9  10  43  65
```

Comment: That works, but you really shouldn't use `apply` with `axis=1` when you can vectorize the code. That would be very slow for a large number of rows

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out what the key difference is, but this works out-of-the-box for my original (and much more complex) dataframe, while the answer by mozway only returns an empty dataframe. Both answers are correct though for my question.

Comment: @Luke can you provide a [mre] of your original DataFrame? Do you have duplicated indices in `filter_.index` or `df.columns`?